# How to group by 2 fields and order by date at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 fields in an `employees` table: `personal_id`, `personal_id_type`, and `date_registered`.

I need to find all the rows, one row for each `personal_id + personal_id_type` (here is where I think I can use a GROUP), but since there may be many entries for the same `personal_id + personal_id_type` (because employees can quit and get hired again later), I need to fetch only the newest entry (`order by date_registered DESC`).

Is this conceptually correct? What would be the syntax for grouping by 2 fields? Will I achieve what I need with that?

Edit: I'm sorry, actually there are a lot of fields, so I need the newest row, not only the newest date.

Comment: You explicitly stated "I have 3 fields in an employees table: personal_id, personal_id_type, and date_registered" - not sure how you expected an answer tailored to a different schema.

Comment: I said "I have 3 fields", and not "I have only 3 fields". So it could be read as "I have [at least] 3 fields". Anyway, schemas change in the real world, so I was looking for a general solution (that's why I said  newest entry, and not newest date)

Comment: Another thing: Your problem is of the `[greatest-n-per-group]` type. Look under the **Related** header, at the right for similar questions.

Comment: K, thanks for the info. I noted you added the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the newest date for every `(personal_id, personal_id_type)` combination in a subquery, then join to the original table:

```
SELECT
    e.*
FROM
    employees e
  JOIN   
    ( SELECT
          personal_id
        , personal_id_type
        , MAX(date_registered) AS latest_date_registered
      FROM
          employees
      GROUP BY
          personal_id
        , personal_id_type
    ) AS grp
    ON  grp.personal_id = e.personal_id
    AND grp.personal_id_type = e.personal_id_type
    AND grp.latest_date_registered = e.date_registered
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer I was looking for. I'll be testing the query

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
select personal_id, personal_id_type, max(date_registered)
from employees 
group by personal_id, personal_id_type
```

Conceptually, you are not ordering by date, since you are returning only one per personal_id/personal_id_type combination. Since you are using GROUP BY, you use an aggregate function to select the MAX date.

Comment: I'm sorry but actually there are a lot of fields, so I need the newest row, not only the newest date.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    personal_id,
    personal_id_type,
    MAX(date_registered) AS latest_date_registered
FROM
    Employees E
GROUP BY
    personal_id,
    personal_id_type
```

If you need additional columns then you'll need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but actually there are a lot of fields, so I need the newest row, not only the newest date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT personal_id, personal_id_type, MAX(date_registered)
FROM employees
GROUP BY personal_id, personal_id_type
ORDER BY MAX(date_registered) DESC
```

Comment: This does not address his grouping/aggregate issue.

Comment: Does it not?  It groups on all none-aggreagate fields, and then orders the records by the latest date_registered downwards.

Comment: He doesn't want it ordered, he only wants the newest `date_registered`. The `order by` will push the newest row to the top, but all the other rows are still included in the query, hence the `MAX` aggregate function... and I see he edited his question, so never mind.

Comment: I'm sorry but actually there are a lot of fields, so I need the newest row, not only the newest date.

Answer (score 0):

This is where aggregate functions become useful. You will group by `personal_id` and `personal_id_type`, then use `MAX(date_registered)` to select the newest date. Just remember that you have to group by all non-aggregate columns.

Comment: I'm sorry but actually there are a lot of fields, so I need the newest row, not only the newest date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct:

```
SELECT 
    personal_id, 
    personal_id_type, 
    MAX(date_registered) AS latest_date
FROM 
    employees 
GROUP BY 
    personal_id,
    personal_id_type
ORDER BY
    MAX(date_registered) DESC
```