# Select rows from table where two colmns form a distinct set and order by third field

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have one table called `route_timetables` which contains timetables for bus routes.

Each row contains one timetable for one direction(i.e north, south, east, and west) and for one type of day(i.e, weekday, Saturday and Sunday).

I need to get the most current timetables for each route.  So where route id=X and the route publish_date has passed, I need to get the most current timetables where the direction and type are distinct.  It will likely return 6 rows, one for say West, on weekdays, Saturdays, and Sundays, and one for East on weekdays, Saturdays, and Sundays.
The table fields looks like this

```
id   route_id    timetable    publish_date    direction    type
```

I have tried several different approaches.   I thought this code was working but it was querying an old timetable that also was for weekdays, traveling west.

```
SELECT timetable, direction, type, MAX(publish_date)
            FROM route_timetables
            WHERE publish_date<=curDate() and route_id=2
            GROUP BY direction, type
```

Comment: you say `the table looks like this` but include no table.

Comment: One thing that's suspicious is that you haven't included timetable in your group by statement.  In other SQL variants this would fail but I believe mysql is more forgiving - still looks wrong though.

Comment: sorry I forgot to include the table structure

Comment: What is timetable column type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here [How to group by 2 fields and order by date at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082379/how-to-group-by-2-fields-and-order-by-date-at-the-same-time)  and re-purposed it.

```
SELECT
rt.*
FROM
route_timetables rt
JOIN   
( SELECT
      direction
    , type
    , MAX(publish_date) AS latest_date_registered
  FROM
      route_timetables
  WHERE publish_date<=curDate()
  GROUP BY
      direction
    , type
) AS grp
ON  grp.direction = rt.direction
AND grp.type = rt.type
AND grp.latest_date_registered = rt.publish_date
Where route_id=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate table which contains an id (PK), the timetable and direction. Have this new table's id as a FK in your current table and you could call DISTINCT() on this FK.

I suggest this as it sounds like you are having repeating values of timetable and/or direction.

Answer (score 0):

Join in the publish date information:

```
SELECT rt.*
FROM route_timetables rt JOIN
     (SELECT direction, type, route_id, MAX(publish_date) as maxpd
      FROM route_timetables
      WHERE publish_date <= curDate() and route_id = 2
      GROUP BY direction, type, route_id
     ) dtr
     ON dtr.route_id = rt.route_id and dtr.type = dt.type and dtr.direction = dtr.direction and
        dtr.maxpd = tr.publish_date ;
```

This is the right idea.  Without sample data, it is hard to tell if the right fields are being used for the aggregation and `on` clause.